# I cannot work with Smart Contract using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethers.js

I've been trying to link a smart contract with ethers.js in my project.

```
const Provider= new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
  `https://goerli.infura.io/v3/`
);
```

const TokenContract = new ethers.Contract(
TokenAddress,
abiSource.token.abi,
Provider
);`

I tried to run this but couldn't get the balance of the token contract.
Extracted RPC link from the Metamask.
Who can help me with this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you didn't use Infura georli api key.

```
const Provider= new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
  `https://goerli.infura.io/v3/ca11249dabe247c1a6e0877c24376dda`
);
```

Please try the above.
However, you must bring your own Infura API Key.

Comment: Thank you very much. I connected Smart Contract with your RPC link.
Then, could you let me know how to get Infura API Key?

Comment: Just a by the way; `ethers.providers.WebsocketProvider` is faster than `ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider` would advice switching to that